# Robolectric not calling Application.onCreate()

Tags: android, robolectric

I am very much new to *Robolectric*. I am facing these issues after migrating from *Robolectric* v3.0 to v3.4.1.

1. *Robolectric* is not loading my `AppController` class which extends `Application`
2. I am getting class cast exception on casting to `RuntimeEnvironment.application` to my `AppController`, which shouldn't be the case as my `AppController` extends `Application` and was working fine before migrating to latest version.

Please find the code below for my test

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, manifest = "app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml", sdk = 21)
public class FragmentTest {

private ExampleFragment fragment = SupportFragmentController.of(new ExampleFragment()).create().get();
private Context mContext;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
   // RuntimeEnvironment.application.onCreate();
   mContext =RuntimeEnvironment.application ;
}

@Test
public void testFragmentInstantiation() {
   ExampleFragment.mAppController = (AppController)mContext;

}
```

To reproduce - run any test.

*Robolectric* version is 3.4.1.

Answer (score 1):

The main advice is to do not put manifest file location in the `@Config` section unless you know what you're doing. So please change your test annotations to:

```
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21)
```

Also, I don't know if it is by purpose but you could use much newer android sdk in your test with the newest version of *Robolectric*